# Finding wi-fi networks that are nearby via iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have to build an App that responds if a special Wi-Fi network is nearby.

Is it possible get a list of wi-fi networks that are nearby. If so, please let know, so that I have an idea how to solve this.

Best regards, Jennifer

Comment: This goes for majoroty of your questions: is this ment for a non-jailbroken iphone and for an app store app or for private (off app store) use? +1: interesting questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone get a list of all SSIDs without private library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684341/iphone-get-a-list-of-all-ssids-without-private-library)

Answer (score 5):

No there is no API in the SDK that will allow you to get a list of WiFi networks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a jailbreaked iOS Device and check out this https://github.com/mustafa96m/iOS-Wireless-Scanner-API

Hopefully It Helps :P