# Swift get list of available wifi network and connect to one of them

Tags: ios, swift, captivenetwork, networkextension

I am looking for a solution at least to get list of available SSID and the next step to connect to WiFi SSID via app.

I found `CaptiveNetwork` but it's depreciated in iOS9.

Is there any option to do it using [NetworkExtension](https://bencoding.com/2015/08/04/captivenetwork-depreciated-in-ios9/)? will I have a chance to upload app to the App Store with this functionality.

Comment: do you want solution using **only** `NetworkExtension` framework?

Comment: @DashAndRest, I am open to any solution)

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander Did you find solution for this, is it possible with NetworkExtension ? I am looking for the same thing but not getting proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808492/how-to-detect-all-available-wifi-networks-and-connect-to-one-of-them-in-an-ios-a?rq=1), and simply says:

> you can't do this, at least not if you want to be able to publish on the App Store.

I hope this is similar to your query!

Comment: yea that's why I am asking because I found different versions of possibility to do it. someones say that this is not possible and some posts says to use some frameworks, libraries and etc.