# iPhone check if a particular SSID is available

Tags: ios, wifi, ssid

I've been searching for a solution to a problem similar to this one:

[iPhone get a list of all SSIDs without private library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684341/iphone-get-a-list-of-all-ssids-without-private-library)

So apparently you can't get the SSID of a network you're not connected to without using a private library. I was wondering if it's possible to do it the other way around. So if I know the SSID of a particular network, can I check if it's available/in range without actually connecting to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing has really changed on this in the last year since the previous answer you've found. I work on the Enterprise side of the fence so I luckily don't have to worry about private APIs affecting my apps. It all boils down to Apple not wanting to allow developers to do sleeve things behind the end-users' backs.

To answer your question directly, no, you can't programmatically determine WiFi networks in range without the use of Private APIs. Sorry.