# Is there a way to Connect with a Wi-Fi Modem via my iOS app without using Settings Page?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi, settings

I want to connect with a Wi-Fi Modem via my iOS app. I don't want the user to go to Settings page and Activate Wi-Fi. Is it possible to achieve a Single Button - Pressed & Wi-Fi Connection Activated?

Thanks for your reply!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible unless you use Apple80211 private API, which will be **rejected** from the App Store.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926657/what-is-the-ios-api-for-scanning-available-wi-fi-networks)'s more information on how it's not possible, and [here](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Stumbler)'s a framework for jailbroken phones to use private API and seek/connect to a network.