# Find if Wi-Fi/SSID is in range

Tags: ios, wifi, ssid, networkextension

I want to connect to a SSID from inside the app. I know this is possible with `NEHotspotConfiguration`.

But my problem is that I want to know if or when that wifi is in range, so that the user doesn't try to join the wifi when that is not even in range.

Is there a way to check if a SSID is in range?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926657/what-is-the-ios-api-for-scanning-available-wi-fi-networks  You're looking for the RSSI value, but you can't get that using a public API in iOS.