# Get SSID's in range iOS 7

Tags: ios7, ssid

Seeing as though iOS 7 is out, have Apple made any changes that allow developers to get the SSID's in range, without using private API's, of course.

I have searched StackOverflow and Google regarding this topic, but I haven't found anything to help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone get a list of all SSIDs without private library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684341/iphone-get-a-list-of-all-ssids-without-private-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately nothing has changed, Apple didn't make any changes to allow developers to get the SSID's in range.

Comment: Wow, way to go Apple..Ohh well, guess I'll have to re-design my flipping application again. Guess, I'll have to look at the long list of restrictions Apple have set, then write my application, well what will be left of it.