# React native Wifi list

Tags: list, react-native, wifi, native-module

Is there a way to scan and all get Wifi list using react native for Android and iOS. I have seen a few libraries but mostly for android and even those doesnt work properly. Any suggestions?

If I need to write Native Modules can you point me to right direction. Never wrote a native module for React Native before.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40681984/ios-get-list-of-all-wifi-networks/40683210#40683210

Answer (score 3):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wifi-reborn
Has method `loadWifiList()` gives `Promise<Array<WifiEntry>>`

Also you want to forcefully rescan :
method `reScanAndLoadWifiList()` gives `Promise<Array<string>>`

Comment: The loadWifiList works only for Android

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-native-wifi-reborn` (https://github.com/JuanSeBestia/react-native-wifi-reborn) but there is no way to create a wifi list in iOS.

An explanation of a Apple Support https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/39204

Answer (score -1):

react-native-wifi:
https://github.com/blackdeve/react-native-wifi

You can read docs about Native Modules under **Guide** section. Here are quick links

- [Native Modules - Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html)
- [Native Modules - iOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html)

Here is [react-native-create-library](https://github.com/frostney/react-native-create-library), it will help you to create a React Native library with a single command.

Another blog on Medium about [How to use Native Modules in React Native + Android - Hybrid Apps](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-use-native-modules-in-react-native-android-hybrid-apps-62b67a2cc7ca).

Comment: unfortunately `react-native-wifi` is no longer maintained in 2020 a good fork is `react-native-wifi-rebord` but it does not include this functionality for IOS..