# How to get all available wifi network name listings in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, network-programming

I need to create an app that can get a list of all available wifi networks' names and information on their iPhone, and when the user clicks on some network they should connect to it. Can I do this, and how?

Comment: This will be the possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683210/5167909

Comment: Can you give any example of NetworkExtension how to implementation ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library

Comment: @ Md Rashed Pervez it is displaying only current connected network but i need all network name those are availabel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone get a list of all SSIDs without private library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684341/iphone-get-a-list-of-all-ssids-without-private-library)

Comment: Did you get any perfect answer? I am looking for same functionality. Please help.

Answer (score 9):

It is not possible to get all the available wifi networks names and information. **BUT** it is only possible to get the `SSID` (`SSID` is simply the technical term for a network name) of the network that you are currently connected to.

This class will show only the wifi network name you are connected to -

```
    import UIKit
    import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

        override func viewDidLoad(){
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let ssid = self.getAllWiFiNameList()
            print("SSID: \(ssid)")
        }
        func getAllWiFiNameList() -> String? {
            var ssid: String?
            if let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() as NSArray? {
            for interface in interfaces {
            if let interfaceInfo = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interface as! CFString) as NSDictionary? {
                        ssid = interfaceInfo[kCNNetworkInfoKeySSID as String] as? String
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
            return ssid
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT-** (Network name where i am connected to )

[image]

To test this you need a physical device (iPhone) connected to your pc.

Comment: Yes That i am getting current connected but i want to all list of available network

Comment: Have you any example how to do that..i dont idea how to use it

Comment: What i have done so far..i shared with you. All example will show the name you connected to.Not the list of wifi. you can use Network reachability to show the settings page of you iPhone- then the user will decide where to connect(user will see all the available wifi list there). If you find my answer helpful you can accept my answer :). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By doing some research I found that:
**It is NOT possible in iOS to scan all nearby SSID. We can only get currently connected wifi SSID.**
If we somehow do this with any private library, App will be rejected by Apple.
Some helpful Links I want to share -

- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/39204
- [iOS 11.0 - Periodically scan for SSIDs (WiFi) nearby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451287/ios-11-0-periodically-scan-for-ssids-wifi-nearby)

You can get connected wifi **SSID** by these methods:
**Swift (3 and 4)** -

```
import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork

func fetchSSIDInfo() -> String? {
        var ssid: String?
        if let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() as NSArray? {
            for interface in interfaces {
                if let interfaceInfo = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interface as! CFString) as NSDictionary? {
                    ssid = interfaceInfo[kCNNetworkInfoKeySSID as String] as? String
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        return ssid
    }
```

**Objective-C** -

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/CaptiveNetwork.h>

+(NSString*)fetchSSIDInfo {

    NSArray *ifs = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();

    NSDictionary *info;

    for (NSString *ifnam in ifs) {

        info = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((__bridge CFStringRef)ifnam);

        if (info && [info count]) {

            return [info objectForKey:@"SSID"];
            break;
        }
    }

    return @"No WiFi Available";
}
```

Comment: so is there really no way to this ?  to scan all nearby SSIDs ??. We can only get currently connected wifi SSID ?? in iOS?

Comment: Wrong answer. You can get the nearby networks.

Comment: Alexander Volkov, please reference some documentation or write an answer, not a comment, on how to do this. It's not helpful to simply contradict someone without supporting your claim.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.You need to complete a questionnaire at https://developer.apple.com/contact/network-extension, and then you can use NEHotspotHelper to return a list of hotspots.

Comment: NEHotspotNetwork will only return a list of networks when the user navigates to the Wi-Fi page in Settings. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52473480/35690 for more details.