# how to get available wifi network in ios swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift4

I want get all available wifi network iphone .
I use this code

```
import SystemConfiguration
import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork
func fetchSSIDInfo() -> String {
var currentSSID = ""
if let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() {
for i in 0..<CFArrayGetCount(interfaces) {
let interfaceName: UnsafeRawPointer = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(interfaces,i)
let rec = unsafeBitCast(interfaceName, to: AnyObject.self)
 print("teseeeeeeeee :\(rec)")           
let unsafeInterfaceData = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo("\(rec)" as CFString)
  if let interfaceData = unsafeInterfaceData as? [String: AnyObject] { currentSSID = interfaceData["SSID"] as! String
 let BSSID = interfaceData["BSSID"] as! String
let SSIDDATA = interfaceData["SSIDDATA"]
 debugPrint("ssid=\(currentSSID), BSSID=\(BSSID), SSIDDATA=\(SSIDDATA)")}}} return currentSSID}
```

this show in currentssid i want get all wifi ssid

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525912/how-to-get-available-all-wifi-network-name-listing-in-ios-using-swift/51005384

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get available all wifi network name Listing in iOS using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525912/how-to-get-available-all-wifi-network-name-listing-in-ios-using-swift)

Comment: this are get Current wifi ssid i want all wifi ssid list

Comment: this also get current wifi ssid (all ready connected wifi ssid) i want get all available wifi ssid

Answer (score 0):

You cannot,
if you use NEHotspotHelper, it was not designed as a general-purpose Wi-Fi scanning API and any attempt to use it as such will run into both business and technical problems. 
read this [`article`](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/276151#276151) also refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1942/_index.html)