# How to scan nearby Wifi devices in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, wifi

I want to implement code for scan the nearby wifi devices.
I am not getting proper solution for this after doing lots of research.
Can you please give me proper solution to scan the nearby wifi devices?
I have implemented below code. It only getting information of wifi which is already connected.
Below is the code:

```
func getInterfaces() -> Bool {
    guard let unwrappedCFArrayInterfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() else {
        print("this must be a simulator, no interfaces found")
        return false
    }
    guard let swiftInterfaces = (unwrappedCFArrayInterfaces as NSArray) as? [String] else {
        print("System error: did not come back as array of Strings")
        return false
    }
    for interface in swiftInterfaces {
        print("Looking up SSID info for \(interface)") // en0
        guard let unwrappedCFDictionaryForInterface = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interface as CFString) else {
            print("System error: \(interface) has no information")
            return false
        }
        guard let SSIDDict = (unwrappedCFDictionaryForInterface as NSDictionary) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            print("System error: interface information is not a string-keyed dictionary")
            return false
        }
        print(SSIDDict)
    }
    return true
}
```

It return output is below.

```
Looking up SSID info for en0
["SSIDDATA": <4575726f 74726f6e 6963>, "BSSID": d4:3d:37:14:9:2f, "SSID": Vikas]
```

Can you please help me to scan the nearby wifi devices functionality?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525912/how-to-get-available-all-wifi-network-name-listing-in-ios-using-swift

Comment: Tried this. It only shows networks that are connected. I want to scan nearby all devices.