# Get list of all available Wifi Connections and choose one to connect inside an App in iOS 11

Tags: ios, networking, wifi

In iOS 11 Apple has added NEHotspotConfiguration and NEHotspotConfigurationManager

I am trying to build an app - where:

1. User opens the app
2. User scans for available Wifi networks
3. User selects to connect a network

Have tried below links:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfiguration

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotconfigurationmanager

Comment: only you got connected wifi name you can't get the name of available wifi networks

Comment: That API won't work for exactly what you're trying to do. However, both NEHotspotConfiguration and NEHotspotNetwork may do something close to what you want to do. See [the bottom of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52472782/35690) for more info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone get a list of all SSIDs without private library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684341/iphone-get-a-list-of-all-ssids-without-private-library)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible on iOS. The API you have found is the most capable API for interacting with WiFi access points