# How to find nearby hotspots using objective c

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to find all the nearby hotspots using the following code:

```
for(NEHotspotNetwork *hotspotNetwork in [NEHotspotHelper supportedNetworkInterfaces]) {
            NSString *ssid = hotspotNetwork.SSID;
            NSLog(ssid);
            NSString *bssid = hotspotNetwork.BSSID;
            BOOL secure = hotspotNetwork.secure;
            BOOL autoJoined = hotspotNetwork.autoJoined;
            double signalStrength = hotspotNetwork.signalStrength;
        }
```

I ran this code in the simulator after the user clicks a button.
However, [NEHotspotHelper supportedNetworkInterfaces] returns nil.
I don't  understand why.

Comment: It's my first experience with IOS development, so I'll try to run it on an actual device to see if it helps

Comment: I tried running it on actual device and still got nil

Comment: Do you have the necessary entitlements? You can't participate in NEHotspotHelper without special application to Apple. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823754/how-can-i-get-available-wifi-list-with-nehotspothelper-ios-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Check [NEHotspotHelper](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspothelper) class documentation. You will need **com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotHelper**
entitlement to work with NEHotspotHelper class. 
You have to contact Apple to request this entitlement.